# Are Facebook checkins deprecated in favor of Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-checkins

Does anyone know whether the checkins graph object and its API are still the right way to think about, post, and retrieve checkins on Facebook? Are they moving to deprecate them in favor of geocoded posts?

Would be really grateful if someone could help clarify checkins vs. OG.

Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic.  This site is for **programming related questions** (which yours is not).  You should try ask your question here : https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: Thanks. This community's regulation of its practices and scope of specific purpose - which I am only just learning about and appreciating - is quite impressive!

Comment: Haha - glad you like it Simon :P  And yes - we take the content of this site very seriously.

Answer (score 2):

There's no deprecation of checkins on the [roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) - if there were there'd be 90 days notice of their removal